# GraphQL Schema for Nested JSON?

Tags: json, schema, graphql

I am trying to use GraphQL to deal with some JSON data. I can retrieve fields from the top level no problem. I can associate separate JSON objects also no problem. My problems are occurring trying to get at data one level down. So, I have defined a type in my schema for staff. The json looks like this:

```
"staff": [
 {
   "id": 123,
   "name": "fred",
   "role" : "designer",
   "address": {
     "street": "main street",
     "town": "Springfield"
   }
 },
 ...
]
```

and the corresponding type in the schema looks like this so far:

```
const StaffType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Staff',
    fields: {
      id: {type: GraphQLInt},
      name: {type: GraphQLString},
      role: {type: GraphQLString}
    }
})
```

This works fine as far as retrieving the id, name and role goes. My question is how can I extend `StaffType` to also retrieve `street` and `town` from the `address` field in the original JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I was getting hung up on the idea of a distinct Type in the schema having to refer to a separate piece of JSON whereas, in fact, I can define an AddressType in the schema to refer to the nested data and then include it in the StaffType without having to write a resolve function.

[edit to add example]

```
const StaffType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Staff',
    fields: {
      id: {type: GraphQLInt},
      name: {type: GraphQLString},
      role: {type: GraphQLString},
      address: {type: AddressType}
    }
})

const AddressType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Address',
    fields: {
      street: {type: GraphQLString},
      town: {type: GraphQLString}
    }
})
```

Comment: If you are still active.  I am facing this issue now, any additional assistance you could provide would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, what worked for me was defining a separate type for Address and then referring to that in the StaffType. I've edited my answer above to show an example.

Comment: Thanks @Drum.  I asked a new question just in-case and also received helpful advice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440547/schema-from-nested-json-list?noredirect=1#comment87905259_50440547.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi, how do you handle the resolving afterward? Doesn't this schema means that you need 2 resolvers, one for Staff and one for Address now ?